# Making a value 0 when it is null when using Jasper Studio

Tags: jasper-reports

I am aware of how make a null value 0 for certain simple values. For example, I set the following expression for my text field:

```
($V{current_val_subtotal} != null) ? $V{current_val_subtotal} : "0.00"
```

where `$V{current_val_subtotal}` is `BigDecimal`. But I was trying to do the following:

```
(($F{CurrentValue}.doubleValue()/$V{current_val_subtotal}.doubleValue())*100 != null) ? ($F{CurrentValue}.doubleValue()/$V{current_val_subtotal}.doubleValue())*100 : “0.00”
```

where `$F{CurrentValue}` is `BigDecimal`.

When previewing the report I get the following errors:

```
The operator != is undefined for the argument type(s) double, null
Errors were encountered when compiling report expression class file:
```

Comment: @DmitrySmorzhok is right. If at all, you should check `($V{current_val_subtotal} != null)` at the beginning to avoid a division by zero.

Answer (score 1):

What are you actually expecting? What is the meaning of expression `someDouble / someDouble != null`?

You have a division of two primitives which will never result in null: you can get either a double if both BigDecimal are non-null or NullPointerException otherwise. That is why you're getting a compilation error.

You probably want something like this

```
($F{CurrentValue} != null && $V{current_val_subtotal} != null) ? 
($F{CurrentValue}.doubleValue() / $V{current_val_subtotal}.doubleValue() * 100) : 0
```

or

```
($F{CurrentValue} != null && $V{current_val_subtotal} != null) ?
($F{CurrentValue}.divide($V{current_val_subtotal}, 2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP).multiply(new BigDecimal(100)) : BigDecimal.ZERO
```